# How to send clone of object c++

Tags: c++

So I have a for loop that has it so I send an object to a function. I set the address of the object received to a pointer, but that makes it so that when I change the original object, the object's that were pointing to it's address change as well, and I don't want that. Is it possible to do a .clone() in c++ for the objects I send?

Comment: C++ don't have ".clone()". If you want to use copy of your object then better to implement copy constructor for this object.

Comment: Pass-by-value is what you want here:  e.g. `void MyFunction(MyObjectType obj);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a copy of the object you probabily should not pass a pointer reference. Just use a value argument in your function.

Comment: So I'm not passing a pointer reference, but I'm setting a pointer to the object that is passed.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0):

In case if your "send" function works with values you can use object by value.
But if "send" works with pointers or it's nessesary to "clone" object for another reason you can implement copy constructor.

Here is a simple code example:

```
#include<iostream>

class SomeClass {
    int someData;

public:
    // Simple constructor
    SomeClass(int data) : someData(data) {}

    //Copy constructor
    SomeClass(const SomeClass& o) : someData(o.someData) {}

    void Print() {
        std::cout << someData << '\n';
    }

    void ChangeData(int data) {
        someData = data;
    }
};

void send(SomeClass* o) {
    // do something
    o->ChangeData(43);
}

int main() {
    SomeClass obj(42);
    SomeClass clonnedObj(obj);
    send(&clonnedObj);
    obj.Print();
    clonnedObj.Print();
}
```

output is

```
42
43
```